# OpenCL Build Error

Tags: java, parallel-processing, kernel, opencl

If I accidentally reference a non-existant function in my OpenCL kernel, even if i fix the problem the compiler acts as if i hadn't. For example.

```
__kernel void doSomething(__global unsigned int *array){
    f(array)
}
```

Clearly f doesn't exist and i will get an error. However if i write the f method, the compiler continues to give this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
Build log for device 0:
kernel referenced an external function f, that could not be found.
```

No matter what i change, i can delete the bodies of any kernels so that the .cl final literally holds no code, and the compiler *still* results in this error. Even making a new file and copying the contents into it, or changing the program parameters or name has no effect. I'm stuck with this bug. Restarting the computer doesn't work either.

**Edit**

I am running this on a MacBook Pro, version 10.9

Comment: It is simple, you are not really changing the source code. Check the string just before you send it to the compiler and you will see the actual code that goes to the compiler.

Comment: The code being sent to the compiler is the updated code without the error. It may help to know that I'm using JOCL to compile the kernel.

Comment: It is impossible that you compile an empty `.cl` file and the compiler complains about a kernel referencing a function "f". Clearly you are still compiling the old kernel source. Just dump the source being sent to the compiler, just there, before the compiling.

Comment: What i mean by empty, is that the .cl file isn't empty, but all the kernels are. In the example above this would mean removing the line "f(array);". And i tried printing the source at compile time and the changes are present yet the error persists.

Comment: Interestingly, it works if i improperly indent random lines.

Comment: JOCL may be caching the source code.  Look for a setting to disable this.  Alternatively, the OpenCL implementation may be doing this caching.  If its the implementation, then report this problem to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with OpenCL caching code in the past and this solved my problem.

```
// Setting this environment variable forces the OpenCL 
// source code to be recompiled every time.
setenv("CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE", "1", 1);
```

Of course, this is only relevant if you're using an NVIDIA platform.